# laravel mutate date for api call only

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Using laravel 5.2, I have an application that is both web based and provides an API. API requests are authenticated using the token guard, while web requests are authenticated using the session guard. I would like to be able to mutate dates so that they are returned as unix timestamps for API calls and the default date string (Y-m-d) for web calls. The best I've been able to come up with is having a separate model for API calls, but I quickly discovered that this leads to issues with polymorphic relationships. Does anyone have a suggestion about how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the serialization to JSON to add a new property that will provide the date formatted the way you want.

https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MyModel extends Model
{

    protected $appends = ['my_date'];

    /**
     * Format date for API calls.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMyDateAttribute()
    {
        return $this->attributes['created_at'] == // format Carbon date here.
    }
}
```

then you'll have a new `my_date` property in the JSON returned by the API call.

Comment: I think this is the best solution for the problem as it allows the default date format to be maintained in the database with the tradeoff of returning two different formats in the returned JSON. If that is an issue, adding the unneccessary date to the $hidden array may be a resolution. Also, for anyone else reading this, don't forget to add the $appends array to the model. For the above example, 'protected $appends = ['my_date'];' should work.

Comment: ah, `$appends` - I forgot that. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could drop a function in your model which formats that attribute how you'd like it to be formatted.

```
public function formatDateForView()
{
    return date('Y-m-d', $this->attributes['your_timestamp_field']);
}
```

And in your view, just call it when you need it.

```
{{ $yourModel->formatDateForView(); }}
```

Comment: I see what you mean, that's kind of the opposite of what I'm after as it provides a way to mutate for the web side only. Ideally I'd like to be able to keep the default format in the database and mutate only for API calls.